# Reading Facebook wall returns an empty array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I am trying to read a user's wall, not news feeds, with PHP, and I always get an empty array from this:

```
$api_call = array(
    'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken()
);

try{
    $wall= $facebook->api("$uid/feed/","get",$api_call);
} catch (Exception $e){}
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `read_stream` extended permission if you want to see posts other than those with visibility set to 'Public'