# Facebook pagination link always return an empty json

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm authenticating myself against FB with the following permissions:

```
"read_stream", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "friends_photos", "friends_likes", "friends_status", "read_friendlists"
```

I manage to do a successful call to `https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/home` with the access token and I get back results, however when following `next` link

```
paging: {
previous: "...",
next: "..."
}
```

I'm getting back an empty json, e.g.

```
{
data: [ ]
}
```

Couple of observations:

- When working with the FB API explorer everything works fine (I've changed the token manually)
- When trying to fetch more posts (say 250) I'm getting also the old posts, e.g. the ones that I should have gotten when calling `next`
- When using a token that was supplied by the api explorer everything works just fine

read couple of posts on this matter - [wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634587/reading-facebook-wall-returns-an-empty-array), [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) all seem to point to wrong permissions, however I've added all permissions and still the same result.